# scss: check parent selector name in mixin

Tags: sass

Is there a way to check what `&` refers in mixin?

```scss
body {
  @import x
}

button {
  @import x
}
```

Inside `@mixin x()` I want a special case when it's called with `body` as `&`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of `&` in your mixin using `@if {} @else {}`:

```
@mixin test {
    $root: #{&};
    $parentTagIsBody: $root == 'body'; 
    
    @if $parentTagIsBody {
        color: red;
    } @else {
        color: black;
    }
}

button {
  @include test;
}

body {
  @include test;
}
```

will compile to:

```
button {
  color: black;
}

body {
  color: red;
}
```